# Bean is no longer being autowired after Spring 5.3 Upgrade

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-bean

I upgraded my package from Spring 4.3 to Spring 5.3 which has caused a issue I am completely to solve, for some reason a Bean that is created and works under 4.3 is being created, but not wired in. The bean is being created, and the configuration has not changed, yet it doesn't work?

Bean Creation:

```
@Configuration
@SuppressWarnings("checkstyle:HideUtilityClassConstructor")
@Slf4j
public class EnvironmentConfig {

    @Bean
    public static AppEnvironmentHelper environmentHelper() throws IOException {
        final AppEnvironmentHelper.Config config = new AppConfigEnvironmentHelper.Confg()
        // Config object is configured

        
        return new AppEnvironmentHelper(config);
    }
}
```

Attempted Injection of Bean:

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class OtherConfig {

    @Value("${role}")
    private String someRole;

    @Value("${port}")
    private String somePort;

    @Autowired
    private EnvironmentHelper environmentHelper;

   .......
}
```

The class path for the bean is in the configuration, and when launching the service I see logs that indicate that EnviromentConfig is created before OtherConfig

`org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Finished creating instance of bean 'environmentHelper'`

But I always get

`UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'OtherConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'environmentHelper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.amazon.coral.spring.EnvironmentHelper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

After it errors spring goes to clean up the beans with

`Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@40db2a24: defining beans [.....,EnvironmentConfig, environmentHelper ]`

Which seems to indicate to me that it is finding the bean, its creating the bean, but then when it comes to wire in enviromentHelper it doesnt find it. Ive tried naming the bean using qualifiers but that did nothing. And I wrapped the EnviromentHelper and added logs during creation of the bean and destruction, so I know the bean isnt being destroyed prematurely. Im not certain what else to try to troubleshoot further.

Comment: Why is the `@Bean` annotated method also `static` ?  And does the `AppEnvironmentHelper` class really implement the correct `com.amazon.coral.spring.EnvironmentHelper` ?

Comment: @cyberbrain The Bean is static because the EnvironmentHelper is based off of `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` which means it has to be static from my understanding. And yes it implements the correct `com.amazon.coral.spring.EnvironmentHelper`